# Cannot install *any* VPN anymore

Tags: windows-7, windows, vpn

Used NORD Vpn perfectly for several years. Then it updated or tried to. Now I get this message when trying to reinstall NORD or other VPN:

Could not open key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER32\Software\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE. Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.

I do not have a _USER32 key, only _USER. I did call regedit as the Admin.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you install Nord as an admin by right clicking on it and select run as admin?

Comment: Yes, I did - still got the same error msg. It's as if the installer is looking in my freezer for strawberry ice cream & all I have is vanilla = HKEY_CURRENT_USER. The strawberry it wants in HKEY_CURRENT_USER32. That key just ain't there. NORD wasn't broke at all until they "fixed" it (updated it).

Answer (score 0):

Open Regedit and delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER32\Software\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\Main
And re-start install package.
For me, it worked